# Colorado Ski Areas GIS dataset

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, ski

I am looking for Colorado ski areas in GIS dataset out there that can I download or request them from an individual that worked on them.

Comment: if you're going to create tags, please be courteous and create them properly in the wiki

Comment: i added that one, i was talking about the "ski" tag that you created...

Answer (score 2):

The USDA Forest Service provides a [Colorado Ski Permitted and Allocated Area Boundaries.](https://www.fs.usda.gov/detail/roadless/coloradoroadlessrules/?cid=stelprdb5291441) It is part of their roadless mapping service.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea this existed.

Comment: Though it is dated in 2009, Things have change and some of them might or might not have an additonal expansion.